# How to access widget in an initializer in google maps flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-maps, flutter-layout

I am passing select latitude and longitude from google maps to my flutter app's another screen where I am calculating the distance between 2 locations.
I've got the values coming fine but there's this `widget` can't be accessed in an initializer issue coming.
I'm using google maps and I've to pass the `widget.lat` `widget.long` values to the `userLocation` marker.

I'm using this tutorial's code by the way
[Get distance between locations](https://www.fluttercampus.com/guide/248/calculate-distance-between-location-google-map-flutter/)

Here's my code

```
class CalculateDistance extends StatefulWidget {
  const CalculateDistance({super.key, required this.lang, required this.lat});

  final double lang;
  final double lat;
  @override
  // ignore: library_private_types_in_public_api
  _CalculateDistanceState createState() => _CalculateDistanceState();
}

class _CalculateDistanceState extends State<CalculateDistance> {
  GoogleMapController? mapController; //contrller for Google map
  PolylinePoints polylinePoints = PolylinePoints();

  String googleAPiKey = "YOUR_API_KEY";

  Set<Marker> markers = {}; //markers for google map
  Map<PolylineId, Polyline> polylines = {}; //polylines to show direction
  LatLng storeLocation =
      const LatLng(-30.600164342582726, 23.508854043469647); // Store location
// This is where I can't use the passed values
  LatLng userLocation = LatLng(widget.lat, widget.lang); // User location

  double distance = 0.0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    markers.add(Marker(
      //add start location marker
      markerId: MarkerId(storeLocation.toString()),
      position: storeLocation, //position of marker
      infoWindow: const InfoWindow(
        //popup info
        title: 'Store Location',
        snippet: 'Store Marker',
      ),
      icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarker, //Icon for Marker
    ));

    markers.add(Marker(
      //add distination location marker
      markerId: MarkerId(userLocation.toString()),
      position: userLocation, //position of marker
      infoWindow: const InfoWindow(
        //popup info
        title: 'User Location',
        snippet: 'User Marker',
      ),
      icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarker, //Icon for Marker
    ));

    getDirections(); //fetch direction polylines from Google API

    super.initState();
  }

  getDirections() async {
    List<LatLng> polylineCoordinates = [];

    PolylineResult result = await polylinePoints.getRouteBetweenCoordinates(
      googleAPiKey,
      PointLatLng(storeLocation.latitude, storeLocation.longitude),
      PointLatLng(userLocation.latitude, userLocation.longitude),
      travelMode: TravelMode.driving,
    );

    if (result.points.isNotEmpty) {
      for (var point in result.points) {
        polylineCoordinates.add(LatLng(point.latitude, point.longitude));
      }
    } else {
      print(result.errorMessage);
    }

    //polulineCoordinates is the List of longitute and latidtude.
    double totalDistance = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < polylineCoordinates.length - 1; i++) {
      totalDistance += calculateDistance(
          polylineCoordinates[i].latitude,
          polylineCoordinates[i].longitude,
          polylineCoordinates[i + 1].latitude,
          polylineCoordinates[i + 1].longitude);
    }
    print(totalDistance);

    setState(() {
      distance = totalDistance;
    });

    //add to the list of poly line coordinates
    addPolyLine(polylineCoordinates);
  }

  addPolyLine(List<LatLng> polylineCoordinates) {
    PolylineId id = const PolylineId("poly");
    Polyline polyline = Polyline(
      polylineId: id,
      color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
      points: polylineCoordinates,
      width: 8,
    );
    polylines[id] = polyline;
    setState(() {});
  }

  double calculateDistance(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2) {
    var p = 0.017453292519943295;
    var a = 0.5 -
        cos((lat2 - lat1) * p) / 2 +
        cos(lat1 * p) * cos(lat2 * p) * (1 - cos((lon2 - lon1) * p)) / 2;
    return 12742 * asin(sqrt(a));
  }
  // Scaffold ahead
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare this `LatLng` with `late` keyword as a member of `_CalculateDistanceState` class:

```
class _CalculateDistanceState extends State<CalculateDistance> {
  late LatLng _userLocation;
  (...)
}
```

Then in the `initState` you will have access to the widget:

```
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  _userLocation = LatLng(widget.lat, widget.lang);
  (...)
}
```

Comment: I've replaced _userLocation in the code and thrown it in initState but it doesn't calculates

Comment: What exactly means it does not calculate? If you stop at a breakpoint in `initState` do you see the passed `lat` and `lang` values of the widget assigned to `_userLocation`?